# CPU utilization calculation

Tags: operating-system, cpu-usage

I've read in many places that a simple and decent way to get the % of CPU utilization is by this formula:

```
CPU utilization = 1 - p^n
```

where:

- `p` - blocked time
- `n` - number of processes

But i can't find an explanation for it. Seems it has to do with statistics, but i can't wrap my head around it.

My starting point is: if i have 2 processes with 50% wait time, then the formula would yield `1 - 1/4 = 75% CPU utilization`. But my broken logic begs the question: if one process is blocked on I/O and the other is swapped in to run when the first is blocked(whatever the burst is), that means that while one waits, the second runs and their wait time overlap. Isn't that `100% CPU utilization`? I think this is true only when the first half of the programs is guaranteed to run without IO need.

Question is: How is that formula taking into account every other possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think in terms of probabilities. If the probability of each of the cores to be idle (waiting for IO) is `0.5` then the probability of the CPU to be in idle is the probability of all of the cores to be in idle at the same time. That is `0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25` and so the probability the CPU is doing work is `1 - 0.25 = 0.75 = 75%`

Comment: so this formula gives the cpu usage at a given time, not over a running session given a number of processes with given characteristics. this is what you are saying, right?

Comment: sorry, i meant the formula gives the chance the cpu is used at a given time

Comment: oh i see. because of how statistics works, given a time line and a 50% chance per unit of time that the cpu is busy, then that means that the cpu is busy 50% on that time line. i guess i was confused because the bursts of cpu busy time vary and didn't know how to determine that(which is irelevant anyway) and my logic was messed. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CPU utilisation is given as **1 - probability of CPU to being in the idle state**

and CPU remain in the idle state when all the process loaded in the main memory is blocked time(I/O)
So if n process has wait time of 50% the probability that all the process are in
block(I/O) state

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).